# How do I preserve the namespace of a DataMember?

Tags: c#, wcf, dynamics-crm

I have two WCF services, `ServiceOne` and `ServiceTwo`.

In `ServiceOne`, I've defined `MyEntity` like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyEntity 
{

    ... // Other members of different types

    [DataMember]
    public Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityReference AccountId { ... } // Notice the namespace
}
```

`ServiceTwo` references `ServiceOne` as well as `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk`, but when I try to do the following in `ServiceTwo`:

```
MyEntity myObject = new MyEntity
{
    AccountId = new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityReference("account", someGuid),
};
```

I get the error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityReference' to 'ServiceTwo.ServiceOneReference.EntityReference'`

Unfortunately, I can't define my own subclass of `EntityReference`, since it's sealed.

Is there a way I can preserve the original namespace of `EntityReference`? I'm I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In service two, what is the namespace of the MyEntity object you trying to create? Its probably ServiceTwo.ServiceOneReference.MyEntity right?

Looks to me like you've used svcutil.ex's to generate a proxy for service one inside the project where service two. Svcutil will most likely create local copies of any classes that the interface on service one returns or consumes, but with namespaces all based in the service one reference.

So hopefully you can set the AccountId property to a new instance of ServiceTwo.ServiceOneReference.EntityReference.... If there's no such thing in your service two project, the EntityReference class may not be serializable.